# Keyboard freezes / stuck if a key pressed repeatedly

Tags: keyboard, freeze, acer

I use Acer 4530.

This problem has happened long since Ubuntu 10.10 and now that I use 11.04 dual booted with Linux Mint 10. Everytime I press one key repeatedly, like when I read a long article in a website/ebook or when I play games which required me to press arrow keys repeatedly, it would randomly freeze. That is, whatever I press on keyboard has no effect, and that also happens with touchpad. However, the USB mouse works just fine. I later found out that it's not actually freeze but more like it's like the key stuck. For example when I play tetris which I usually press w (down) button repeatedly, after some times it would freeze. And if I put the cursor in, say, browser's address bar, it would type "wwww....." infinitely.

The only way I could fix it is by suspend the laptop, either by using mouse or by closing the lid. And instead of suspended, in that case the laptop would automatically wake up and everything will be fine. (Usually my laptop would wake up after suspended by pressing any key)

It has happened since the first time I use Ubuntu, 10.10, and it also happens in Linux Mint 10, and until now in Ubuntu 11.04. It never happened when I use Windows, though.
Anyone has ever encounter similar problem? Anyone know how to fix it permanently?

UPDATE

I just recently installed Windows 7 and Windows 8 Development Preview and both have similar symptoms. So I declare that this problem is not OS specific, probably hardware problem.

Comment: I wonder if we're all on the same page. I think what the original question was trying to explain is, that after the key is pressed and then released.. the letter of what ever key was pressed continues across the screen all on its own. Behaving like the key contacts are shorted together. this is what happens on my machine. Example: Say I press the letter 'K' once and release it, what I see on the screen forever and forever is...KKKKKK...
Also I have to ask, what is meant by 'In Settings->universal access'? I can't find 'settings' or 'universal access'

Comment: Yes I think we have similar problem. Although I now realize that sometimes it's not the same key. Sometimes it's not 'K', I just don't know what it is but my keyboard is still unresponsive. If you use newest Ubuntu if you click the upper left most button you'll get 'System Settings' you click it and there would be an item titled 'Universal Access' or just type in launcher 'universal' you'll find it. However it's not the solution. I've tried it.

Comment: I agree with your observation that it's not freezing, rather, the key is stuck. And yes, I remember it happening in Windows (Vista/7) too. But previously, it was only the non-character keys (e.g. arrows, ctrl, alt, shift, Win) but recently, all character keys are having the same problem too (thus resulting in keys like y repeating yyyyyyyyy even when not held). Usually the stuck key gets restored when I press it again.

Answer (score 2):

Use the folling command in terminal to set the keyboard repeat rate and delay time to whatever works for you.

```
kbdrate [ -r rate ] [ -d delay ]
```

For example, use the following command if you want to set the repeat rate at 20 characters per second and 500 millisecond delay time.

```
sudo kbdrate -r 20 -d 500
```

Test out few other numbers for "-r" and "-d" to find values that work for you.

To make the values stick at every login:

```
gksudo gedit /etc/rc.local
```

And at the end of that file add:

```
kbdrate -r 20 -d 500
```

Save the file and restart your machine.

**Reference**

- [Ubuntu Manuals: keyboard repeat rate and delay time](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/maverick/man8/kbdrate.8.html)

Comment: I'm sorry for my lack of understanding, but when should I do this? Whenever the key got stuck? And how is this exactly fix the problem?

Comment: Once you find a kbdrate that works you need to add to the /etc/rc.local file for the settings to stick at every login.  I edited my answer above.

Comment: Indeed, how does this fix the problem? Repeat rate may reduce the rate of damage, but the damage is still being done. Delays do not help too; once the key gets stuck, it will start repeating unless you press it again.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. I resolved it by turning off the bounce key feature. It's in setting-->universal access

Answer (score 1):

I also had the same issue, and this fixed it for me, but then you lose something too:

> Settings → Keyboard → Turn off Repeat keys

Though now you can't hold a key for a bunch of letters, it should help.

Comment: I turned off using `xset r off` in console, then I realized how much I was depending on arrow keys repeating :(

Answer (score 1):

The problem lies in UNIVERSAL ACCESS --> TYPING
The feature *BOUNCE KEYS* it is meant to ignore fast duplicate key presses.

Just turn it off and it will work perfect

Answer (score 0):

It happens to me on Ubuntu once in a while - when I press and hold an arrow key and then unpress, it looks like the key is pressed (the cursor keeps moving) and the keyboard is stuck (nothing happens if I press any key). Only mouse works.

In that case, one of the following works for me as a workaround:

- use the mouse to Switch user using the top bar. Then the keyboard starts working as usual and you can log back in and continue working
- close the lid or press the shutdown button on the laptop to put the computer to sleep mode. Then wake it up. All then works as usual.

I don't have bounce keys enabled and it still happens from time to time.